# What is the meaning of a LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file in a Xamarin application or library?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In MvvmCross library there is a class Playground.Droid.LinkerPleaseInclude.cs
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/ContentFiles/Android/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs

At line 103 there is a method:

```
public void Include(MvxTaskBasedBindingContext context)
{
  context.Dispose();
  var context2 = new MvxTaskBasedBindingContext();
  context2.Dispose();
}
```

Inside this method it is created an instance of MvxTaskBasedBindingContext class and then immediately it is disposed.
Question: Why it is necessary here to create this instance and after to dispose it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about why an open source package was written the way it was written.

Comment: Why do you recommend me to ask this question on GitHub if on GitHub in "Questions & Help" section for MvvmCross lib directly it is written:                    

"For questions or help we recommend checking:
- The [MvvmCross tag in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvvmcross)
- The [MvvmCross slack channel in the Xamarin Slack](https://xamarinchat.herokuapp.com/)
- Ask your question in the [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/)"

So I'm asking here this question.

Comment: This is a general question about why developers might employ a reference class to avoid an IL linker from marking and sweeping assemblies/types/members. I believe it's valid as it does not only pertain to one open source library in the Xamarin ecosystem.

Answer (score 4):

The `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` is a concept used to prevent Mono's linker from stripping these types from your application. You can read more about this here:

https://github.com/mono/linker/blob/master/src/linker/README.md

What the code you're seeing does prevents these types from being marked and swept by the linker so they are "included" in your application even after the linker strips IL code.

It uses static analysis of your application to determine what assemblies, types, and members are used. If it does not detect these items to be valid, they are marked and swept.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker